# Stripe Connect update connected accounts

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm experimenting with stripe connect

what I'm doing is when a vendor is created on my platfom I also create a stripe connect account for him

```
stripe.accounts.create({type: 'custom', country:'IT'})
```

then I ask the new user to complete the activation process and update the account https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/update

```
stripe.accounts.update(id, req.body);
```

where req.body is (in case of an individual account)

```
{"business_type":"individual",
 "company":null,
 "individual":{
     "first_name":"Sam",
     "last_name":"Morrison",
     "address":{
         "city":"Bergamo",
         "line1":"Via Dipinta,5",
         "postal_code":"24129"
     },
     "dob":{ "year":"1979", "month":"03", "day":"14" }
  }
}
```

but I get an error response that indicate

```
Received unknown parameter: business_type"
```

Comment: What API version are you using? The structure of Connect changed significantly with `2019-02-19` --- if you're using a version before that it'll be different and you may want to upgrade. https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2019-02-19

Comment: Updated to 2019-03-14  stripe.setApiVersion('2019-03-14'); and works as expected! Thanks

Comment: Hey could you share with me the docs where says how to create an account via API as you are doing? I only can create them via a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @duck

```
stripe.setApiVersion('2019-03-14');
```

solve the issue!